# Why I can't find `copy_to_user()` in `man` section 9

Tags: linux-kernel, manual, manpage

I have found `kmalloc()` and `list_for_each_entry()` in `man` command. But, there is no `copy_to_user()`. Why?

Where could I find a full list of kernel functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Debian or Ubuntu, you need to install `linux-manual` package for this:

```
$ sudo aptitude install linux-manual
```

And you need to look for `__copy_to_user` or `copy_to_user_fromio`.